# What is wrong with my Java program for Role based access control?

Tags: java, arraylist, read-write, role-based-access-control

In the attached program I am only looking to get the first part of the output. It should look like this:

```
employee:(Permissions: [rw public, r secret], Subjects: [alice, bob], Parents: [])
manager:(Permissions: [w secret, r top-secret], Subjects: [carol], Parents: [employee])
ceo:(Permissions: [w top-secret], Subjects: [eve], Parents: [manager])
```

But when I run the attached program I get the following output:

```
 rw public  r secret  alice  bob 
  rw public  r secret  alice  bob   w secret  r top-secret  carol 
   rw public  r secret  alice  bob   w secret  r top-secret  carol   w top-secret  eve
```

I know it has to do with the first toString method but I dont know why I can't get the correct format. Also the addParent method, while correct, does not show up at all when I run the current toString method. All of the changes need to be made in the ### class...I think. Please let me know if you can help. Thank you in advance for all the help!

Here is the code:

```
package lecture9
 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner; 

/*
 * A role contains a list of permission objects
 *                 a list of subjects (as strings)
 *                 a list of parents (which roles does this role inherits from)
 *                 a role name
 */
class Role {
    List<Role> parents = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Permission> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
    String name;
    
    // a role must have a name
    Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // add parent role and return 'this' object (to allow method chaining)
    Role addParent(Role parent) {
        parents.add(parent);
        
        return this;
    }
    // add permission object and return 'this' object
    Role addPermission(Permission permission) {
        permissions.add(permission);
        
        return this;
    }
    // add subject (so that the 'subject' will have this role) and return 'this' object
    Role addSubject(String subject) {
        subjects.add(subject);
        
        return this;
    }
    
    // check whether this role has the permission that grants access 'rights' to 'object'
    /*boolean checkPermission(String object, String rights) {
        // TODO
    }
    
    // check whehther 'subject' has the access 'rights' to 'objects'
    boolean checkPermission(String subject, String object, String rights) {
        // TODO
    }*/
    
    // return a string representation of this role (need to include all information)
    public String toString() {
        String par = "";
        String per = "";
        String sub = "";
        
        for(Role r: parents) {
            par = par + " " + r + " ";
            
        }
        
        for(Permission p : permissions){
            per = per + " " + p + " ";
          }
       
        for(String s : subjects) {
            sub = sub + " " + s + " ";
        }
        return par + per + sub;
       
    }
}

/*
 * permission object specifies the access 'rights' to an 'object'
 * both 'rights' and 'object' are strings
 */
class Permission {
    final String object;
    final String rights;
    
    Permission(String object, String rights) {
        this.object = object;
        this.rights = rights;
    }
    // return true if 'object' is the 'object' in this permission and 'rights' is a substring of the 'rights' in this permission
    boolean checkPermission(String object, String rights) {
        return this.object.equals(object) && this.rights.indexOf(rights) >= 0;
    }
    // return string representation of this permission object
    public String toString() {
        return rights + " " + object;
    }
}
  
/*
 * represents a RBAC policy 
 */
public class RBAC {
    // stores all roles in a list
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>(); 
    
    // add a new role to the list
    RBAC addRole(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
        return this;
    }
    // check whether 'subject' has the access 'rights' to 'object'
    /*boolean checkPermission(String subject, String object, String rights) {
        // TODO
    }*/
    // return string representation of the RBAC policy  
    public String toString() {
        String ret = "";
        for(Role r: roles) {
            ret = ret + r + "\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RBAC rbac = new RBAC();
        
        Role employee = new Role("employee")
            .addSubject("alice")
            .addSubject("bob")
            .addPermission(new Permission("public", "rw"))
            .addPermission(new Permission("secret", "r"));
        Role manager = new Role("manager")
            .addSubject("carol")
            .addPermission(new Permission("secret", "w"))
            .addPermission(new Permission("top-secret", "r"))
            .addParent(employee);
        Role ceo = new Role("ceo")
            .addSubject("eve")
            .addPermission(new Permission("top-secret", "w"))
            .addParent(manager);

        rbac.addRole(employee).addRole(manager).addRole(ceo);
        
        System.out.println(rbac);
        
        /*Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your command (e.g. alice r secret):");
        String cmd = in.nextLine().trim(); 

        while(!cmd.equals("")) {
            String[] triple = cmd.split(" ");
            if(triple.length != 3) {
                System.out.println("Illegal command. Try again");
            }
            else {
                String subj = triple[0], op = triple[1], obj = triple[2];
                try {
                    if(rbac.checkPermission(subj, obj, op)) {
                        System.out.printf("%s is allowed to perform %s operation on %s\n", subj, op, obj);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.printf("%s is NOT allowed to perform %s operation on %s\n", subj, op, obj);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
            }
            System.out.println("\nEnter your command");
            cmd = in.nextLine().trim();
        }

        in.close();*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Role.toString:

Change this:

```
public String toString() {
    String par = "";
    String per = "";
    String sub = "";
    
    for(Role r: parents) {
        par = par + " " + r + " ";
        
    }
    
    for(Permission p : permissions){
        per = per + " " + p + " ";
      }
   
    for(String s : subjects) {
        sub = sub + " " + s + " ";
    }
    return par + per + sub;
   
}
```

to this:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.name + ":(Permission: " + permissions + ", Subjects: " + subjects + ", Parents: " +
        parents.stream().map(role->role.name).collect(Collectors.toList()) + ")";
}
```

Comment: this works but the Parents section should just return the word "employee" or "manager" or "ceo" not the whole string. Should i use the trimToSize() function or something else.